# Mad Mimi Error when Trying to Send an e-mail to a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, external, mailer

I put this into my terminal

```
uri = URI('https://api.madmimi.com/mailer/to_list')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri,'username'=>'test@example.com',
'api_key' => 'xxxxxx2ce1ac9eb91c75f5933283eb6c ', 'promotion_name' => 
'bulletin', 'subject' => 'Your Daily Bulletin Update', 'from' => 
'noreply@matsu-namibiaflood.opensciencedatacloud.org/', 'list_name' => 'bulletin')
```

The result was

```
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

On the Mad Mimi API they talk about putting in your user name and API key https://madmimi.com/developer/mailer/methods

What am I doing wrong? Should I put the username and API key elsewhere?

Comment: You should avoid publishing your API keys on Stackoverflow. Use a random string of the same length or ´XXXXX´. The one you have already added in the question should be regarded as compromised - get a new one http://help.madmimi.com/where-can-i-find-my-api-key/.

Comment: my fault. Just made a new API key

Comment: I haven't actually used Mad Mimi but in the API page you linked to they set the `body` or `raw_body` parameter. It could be a required parameter. Authentication errors usually give a 401 Unauthorized response code.

Comment: what do I put in that parameter?

Comment: The body of the email message. `raw_body` being used if you use HTML. This has got to be the worst API documentation I have seen in a while though.

Comment: I included a body and still got the same error

Comment: The url you are using (`'https://api.madmimi.com/mailer/to_list'`) is for [`send to a list`](https://madmimi.com/developer/mailer/send-to-a-list?escape=false) - if you want to send an email you would use `https://api.madmimi.com/mailer` https://madmimi.com/developer/mailer/transactional?escape=false

Answer (score 0):

James here from Mad Mimi, would you mind popping an email to us and I can have a look at your account and check the settings, list names and the promotion.

I would say remove the / at the end of the your "from" email and just check there are no spaces in your API key.

If that doesn't work, I would need to check the promotion but make sure there are no {placeholder} in your bull

Thank you,
James